# How many non-zeros samples in convolution

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, filter-design, convolution, frequency-response

If I have $b[n]$ of length 30 (30 non-zero samples) and $c[n]$ of length 40 (40 non-zero samples).

How many non-zero samples will $a[n]=b[n] * c[n]$ have? (Note '$*$' is a convolution).

I think there will be 30 non-zero samples. Am I correct?

Comment: So, you want to know not just the number of samples from the convolution sum, but how many of them are non-zero. Is it ?

Comment: Yeah I want to know the non-zero samples in a[n].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can't say how many non-zero values $a[n]$ is going to have because, depending on the values that $b[n]$ and $c[n]$ take, $a[n]$ may equal 0 for some values of $n$ or not.

Nevertheless, I think that you want to know the length of the sequence $a[n]$. As a general rule, for two sequences of length $P$ and $L$, the linear convolution between them returns a sequence of length $N=P+L-1$. In this case, the maximum length of $a[n]$ would be $N=30+40-1=69$ (it can be less than 69 if $b[n]$ and $c[n]$ are such that the convolution between them returns null values for the first or the last values of $a[n]$).

The reason why the resulting sequence has a length of $N=P+L-1$ can be easily seen by doing the convolution graphically. Let's assume for simplicity (although the reasoning without these assumptions would be exactly the same) that the first non-zero value of $b[n]$ appears at $n=0$ and that the same thing happens with $c[n]$. Let's remember what the definition of convolution is:

$$a[n]=b[n]*c[n]=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^\infty b[m]c[n-m]$$

This means that we should have in mind $b[m]$ and $c[-m]$, and then start moving $c[-m]$ from $-\infty$ until we get our first non-zero value for $a[n]$. This happens for $n=0$. Then the two sequences always return some information until the last value of $b[m]$ is in the same spot as the first value of $c[n-m]$. This happens for $n=L+P-2=68$. So that leaves us with the length I wrote before: $N=69$.

Comment: My case is: a[n]= b[n] * c[n], length of b is 740 and it have 73 non-zero samples and length of c is 50 with 50 non-zero-samples. How many non-zero samples does a[n] have?

Comment: I don't get it. You said in your question that $b[n]$ had 30 non-zero values and that $c[n]$ had 40. Also, please use the '$' symbol to write mathematical expressions in the future.

Comment: Yeah but now let's consider the case I mention, don't we get 50 non-zero samples?

Comment: No. As I wrote in the answer, the convolution between a sequence of length $P=740$ and $L=50$ would return a sequence of length $N=P+L-1=789$.

Comment: but in $P$ i have $740-73= 667$ all zero values.

Comment: I need to know the non-zero values in $N$

Comment: There is no way to know how many zero-valued samples you get between $n=0$ and $n=P+L-2$ unless you specify which sequences are being convoluted. The only thing that can be known for certain is that $a[n]$ is zero for $n<0$ and for $n>N+P-2$, but what happens in the middle completely depends on the values $b[n]$ and $c[n]$ take. Nothing else can be said without knowing each single value of these two sequences.

Comment: No no!! You are wrong.. $667$ zeros in $P$ would cancel a lot of values..

Comment: I'm affraid I am not. Take for example $b[n]=\delta [n] + \delta [n-49]$ and $c[n]=u[n]-u[n-50]$. The first one is a signal of lenght 50 and it has 48 zero-valued samples. The second one is a signal of length 50 too, and it has no zero-valued samples. The convolution between them turns out to be a sequence of length 99 and it has no zero-valued samples between $n=0$ and $n=98$.

Comment: Man thank you! You are awesome. Greeting from Palestine.

Answer (score 0):

No, you aren't correct.  Convolution is equivalent to multiplying polynomials, with a sequence of length $n$ corresponding to the coefficients of a polynomial (let's say for a variable called $x$) of degree $n-1$.  So convolving sequences with length $n$ and $m$ is equivalent to getting a polynomial of degree $n-1+m-1$ corresponding to a sequence of length $n+m-1$.